# Comparing two objects and update angular

Tags: javascript

Hello all i have values like this

```
const buildings = [
  { id: 111, status: false, image: 'Test1' },
  { id: 334, status: true, image: 'Test4' },
  { id: 243, status: false, image: 'Test7' },
  { id: 654, status: false, image: 'Test9' },
  { id: 222, status: true, image: 'Test8' }
];
```

And new bulding

```
const building =  { id: 222, status: false, image: 'Test2' };
```

You can see that **id** of building is same like id of one **id** in buildings, but value status is now **false** and **image** is different. What i need is to update that value for that **id** in buildings, but also have in mind that sometimes building can look like this

```
const building =  { id: 888, status: false, image: 'Test22' };
```

Then i need just to update buildings with new id from building. I know i can do a push and compare, but i need one function that will do for me, that will receive building and buildings and merge them.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to achieve this, Find would return the same object from `buildings` array if it matches the id. You can update the Object. If Id is not found, you can push the new Object into the Array.

```js
const buildings = [];

function merge(building) {
  console.log('=====================================');
  console.log(`Buildings Before Merge => `, buildings);
  const found = buildings.find(({id}) => building.id === id);
  if (found) {
    Object.assign(found, building);
  } else {
    buildings.push(building);
  }
  
  console.log(`Buildings after Merge => `, buildings);
  console.log('=====================================');
}


const buildingOne =  { id: 222, status: false, image: 'Test2' }; // found will be undefined for this
const buildingOneSameId =  { id: 222, status: true, image: 'Test2Duplicate' }; // in the step, found won't be undefined.
const buildingTwo =  { id: 888, status: false, image: 'Test22' };

merge(buildingOne);
merge(buildingOneSameId);
merge(buildingTwo);
```

Comment: This does not work because found is always undefined

Comment: The problem is that array when init is empty??

Comment: @MiomirDancevic You mean, your main `buildings` array is empty?

Comment: @MiomirDancevic If it empty, it will simply pass new data to it, and if you try passing the same object again, you will get the updated value.

Comment: The problem is that your code newer add new building Id in array, in your array there is always one member

Comment: found will always return undefined, that is problem

Comment: @MiomirDancevic I beleive, I don't follow you question. For more clarity please
 update your question with expected Initailal and final example. For your comment, that my Array has always one Element=> I have kept it empty in my updated code, if it makes things clear.

Comment: i have created some simpe question, thanks in advance 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61632116/update-value-in-array-based-on-same-id-in-angular

Comment: @MiomirDancevic I feel, its basically the same question and probably the same answers mean you are probably missing the explain the exact scenario, Because the example you have given run just fine in the provided answers.

Comment: If you mean to say that your `buildings` array is not defined itself, then add a check to see if `buildings` is defined or else assign an empty array to it. @MiomirDancevic

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to iterate through `buildings` and for same id update the building. In case not match is found, append the `building` into array

```js
const buildings = [{ id: 111, status: false, image: 'Test1' },{ id: 334, status: true, image: 'Test4' },{ id: 243, status: false, image: 'Test7' },{ id: 654, status: false, image: 'Test9' },{ id: 222, status: true, image: 'Test8' }],
      firstBuilding =  { id: 222, status: false, image: 'Test2' },
      secondBuilding =  { id: 888, status: false, image: 'Test22' };

const updateBuilding = (building) => {
  let isPresent = false;
  if(buildings && buildings.length === 0) 
    return [{...building}];
    
  return buildings.reduce((r, b, i, buildings) => {
    if(b.id === building.id) {
      r.push({...building});
      isPresent = true;
    } else {
      r.push({...b});
    }
    if(!isPresent && i === buildings.length - 1) {
      r.push({...building});
    }
    return r;
  },[]);
}


console.log(updateBuilding(firstBuilding));
console.log(updateBuilding(secondBuilding));
```

Comment: Can you make it like function i typescript and not const? And the problem i have is that in init  array buildings is empty

Comment: You want to incrementally build the array, isn't it?

Comment: Added a check for empty array. You just replace your array with new array returned after the function call.