# Update value in array based on same id in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this array

```
const buildings = [
  { id: 111, status: false, image: 'Test1' },
  { id: 334, status: true, image: 'Test4' },
  { id: 243, status: false, image: 'Test7' },
  { id: 654, status: false, image: 'Test9' },
  { id: 222, status: true, image: 'Test8' }
];
```

What I need is to update same value based on new porperti

```
cons newBuilding = { id: 111, status: true, image: 'Test1' };
```

I need a function that will handle like that like this

```
    mergeSelectedBuildings(building) {
    if (buildings.length >= 0) {
      buildings.push(building);
    } else {
      buildings.map((buildingValue, i) => {
        if (buildingValue.id === building.id) {
          this.buildings[i].status = building.status;
          this.buildings[i].image = building.image;
        } else {
          this.buildings.push(building);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

The problem is that this does not work as expected, it always add new and new value it does not update:(

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use the `map` array function like this. Instead, try to find the item and update that object. If the item isn't found, push the building to the array.

```js
mergeSelectedBuildings(building) {
  const existing = this.selectedBuildings.find(x => x.id === building.id);
  if (existing) {
    existing.status = building.status;
    existing.image = building.image;
  } else {
    this.selectedBuildings.push(building);
  }
}
```

Comment: const currentBuilding = buildings.find(building => building.id === newBuilding.id); will return undefined

Answer (score 1):

You need to find object from array that is equal to `id`, then if it's not existing in array, you need to push it, else you need to update values of existing building object

```js
mergeSelectedBuildings(newBuilding) {
  const currentBuilding = buildings.find(building => building.id === newBuilding.id);
  if (!currentBuilding) {
    buildings.push(newBuilding);
    return;
  }
  currentBuilding.status = newBuilding.status;
  currentBuilding.image = newBuilding.image;
}
```

Example of usage:

```js
console.log(buildings);

mergeSelectedBuildings(newBuilding);

console.log(buildings);
```

output:

```js
[
  { id: 111, status: false, image: 'Test1' },
  { id: 334, status: true, image: 'Test4' },
  { id: 243, status: false, image: 'Test7' },
  { id: 654, status: false, image: 'Test9' },
  { id: 222, status: true, image: 'Test8' }
]
[
  { id: 111, status: true, image: 'Test1' },
  { id: 334, status: true, image: 'Test4' },
  { id: 243, status: false, image: 'Test7' },
  { id: 654, status: false, image: 'Test9' },
  { id: 222, status: true, image: 'Test8' }
]
```

Comment: const currentBuilding = buildings.find(building => building.id === newBuilding.id); Will return undefined

Comment: Only if there is no building with specified `id`, then `if (!currentBuilding)` will be executed

Answer (score 0):

please try this snippet

```js
const buildings = [
  { id: 111, status: false, image: 'Test1' },
  { id: 334, status: true, image: 'Test4' },
  { id: 243, status: false, image: 'Test7' },
  { id: 654, status: false, image: 'Test9' },
  { id: 222, status: true, image: 'Test8' }
];


const newBuilding = { id: 111, status: true, image: 'Test1' };

var b = buildings.find(e => e.id == newBuilding.id)
b.image = newBuilding.image
b.status = newBuilding.status
console.log(buildings)
```

this finds the building by `id` property

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function:

```js
const buildings = [
   ...
];

const update = (item: { id: number, status: boolean, image: string }): void {
   const index = buildings.findByIndex(current => current.id === item.id);
   if(index !== -1) {
      buildings[index] = item;
   }
}
```